# How can I display elements that are not outdated with Vue.js and firebase?

Tags: javascript, date, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

Here is how I fetch data from Firebase. I can print all my list of events and i'm quite happy for that but now i would like to only load "Events" that are not outdated ? I'm stuck.

Huge thanks for your help :)
Max,

```
    loadEvents ({commit}) {
  commit('setLoading', true)
  firebase.database().ref('events').once('value')
    .then((data) => {
      const events = []
      const obj = data.val()
      for (let key in obj) {
        events.push({
          id: key,
          title: obj[key].title,
          day: obj[key].day,
          description: obj[key].description,
          imageUrl: obj[key].imageUrl,
          date: obj[key].date,
          location: obj[key].location,
          creatorId: obj[key].creatorId
        })

      }
      commit('setLoadedEvents', events)
      commit('setLoading', false)
    })
    .catch(
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
        commit('setLoading', false)
      }
    )
},
```

EDIT : thanks to Frank now i can selected only the nodes who have something correct in the field "expires". If there is something wrong like text in this field, the nodes is not displayed. How can I get only the nodes where the date (timestamp) in the field "expires" is upper than the date of yesterday ?

```
     loadMeetups ({commit}) {
  commit('setLoading', true)
  firebase.database().ref('Meetups').orderByChild('expires').startAt(Date.now()).once('value')
    .then((data) => {
      const Meetups = []
      const obj = data.val()
      for (let key in obj) {
        Meetups.push({
          id: key,
          title: obj[key].title,
          day: obj[key].day,
          expires: obj[key].expires,
          description: obj[key].description,
          imageUrl: obj[key].imageUrl,
          date: obj[key].date,
          location: obj[key].location,
          creatorId: obj[key].creatorId
        })
      }
```

Here is how i push my data on Firebase :

```
  methods: {
  onCreateMeetup () {
    if (!this.formIsValid) {
      return
    }
    const MeetupData = {
      title: this.title,
      day: this.day,
      expires: this.expires,
      location: this.location,
      imageUrl: this.imageUrl,
      description: this.description,
      date: this.submittableDateTime
    }
    this.$store.dispatch('createMeetup', MeetupData)
    this.$router.push('/Meetups')
  }
}
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jotFj.png) are a sample of my data

Best,

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit on the definition of when a node expires. If you store the timestamp of when a child node becomes outdated, e.g.

```
child.expires = Date.now();
```

Then you can query for nodes that haven't expired with:

```
firebase.database().ref('events').orderByChild('expires').startAt(Date.now()).once('value')
  .then((data) => {
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Frank!
Where do i have to declare : 
     child.expires = Date.now(); ?

I tried here but doesn't seems to work

    loadConcerts ({commit}) {
      commit('setLoading', true)
      child.expires = Date.now()
      firebase.database().ref('events').orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(Date.now()).once('value')
        .then((data) => {
          const concerts = []
          const obj = data.val()

Comment: For this to work you have to have a timestamp property in your child nodes. How you do that depends on how you currently write those nodes, because that's where you have to add it. If you need help with that, add the code that you currently use to write the nodes to your question.

Comment: here is the git where you can find the code : https://github.com/academind/yt-devmeetup-vue-firebase/blob/19-fetch-initial-user-state/src/store/index.js

An huge thanks to spend your time on my problem

Comment: maybe i have to store the information on firebase when a nodes expires ?

Comment: That's indeed what I tried to explain: store the timestamp of when the node expires when you create that node. Something along the lines of `payload.expires = new Date("2019-01-01").getTime()` in your `registerUserForMeetup` function.

Comment: Ok i now store the expires date. So i have to make a function who says if expires.date > date.now() then do not display the element. But still don't know where to declare this function.. Thanks Frank

Comment: I updated my answer to contain the query you need to load only nodes that haven't expired yet. That should be a drop-in replacement for how you currently load the items, it just load fewer of them. If that doesn't work, update your question to show what you tried.